# Local symbols are displayed incorrectly in Visual Studio Debugger (C#)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm working on a Project (c#) and have the following problem when debugging a succesfull build.

When putting breakpoints in the Source Code or pausing the execution of the application
strange things happen...
I'm using the "Local" Tab at the bottom to check and control the values in the objects and variables, but the output at this position looks like a mess ^^

Actually i tried almost everything i know to change and setup the configuration of the Visual Studio.
I also tried to start a new c# project and repair and reinstall the VS and so on.
But nothing really worked.

But on an other PC and working with the same VS-Edition and the same Project, everything is fine.

attached there are two screenshots of the failure... so i need your help.. any ideas..?

---

correct one:
[steve-krieghoff.net/gundg/msdn/forum/true.png](http://steve-krieghoff.net/gundg/msdn/forum/true.png)

---

wrong one
[steve-krieghoff.net/gundg/msdn/forum/false.png](http://steve-krieghoff.net/gundg/msdn/forum/false.png)

Comment: This issue has been mentioned before on SO, but I have no link to it. From what I can see the debugger confuses C# code with C++. It might be a setting or more likely a VS bug.

Comment: that's hat we think here tooo... but we can't find out how to fix this bug and the strange thing is, 3 oder 4 days ago.. everything was fine.. and this problem apeared without any changes in settings or installations

Comment: First of all I am wondering if you have found the root cause of that problem? And then did you try to compare the registry settings between the machines?